# Python random number generator error. WindowsError: [Error -2146893818] Invalid Signature

Tags: python, windowserror

What is wrong with the built-in python RNG?
This line keeps crashing my application

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 113, in seed
    a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(2500)), 16)
WindowsError: [Error -2146893818] Invalid Signature
```

The error only occurs when I try to run python from a web application with PHP's proc_open().

Comment: What code did you use to generating this error?

Comment: import sqlalchemy. That's all

Comment: ...You're using PHP on Windows to launch Python. ...I hope you're aware of just how many "wat"s that causes.

Comment: It's getting platform independent. The latest versions of Windows support POSIX, so I see no problem here other than some monkey job has to be done with syscalls.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned out to be a PHP problem, not OS level, so highly unlikely you could've helped without the code, but i'll leave this here if anyone faces the same problem.

**This is an environment variable issue.** When calling `proc_open()`, PHP uses operating system level environment variables unless you specify `$env` as the fifth argument. The error in my case was that I remembered incorrectly that `$env` has to be specified, and I used an empty array as its value, which overtook OS level path definitions. Removed `$env` and `$cwd` and it worked like a charm.